# How to install MonoGame templates on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monodevelop, monogame

The readme says I should copy the MonoDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 directory into ~/.config/MonoDevelop/addins directory. When I do this, I see no new templates, nor any new plugins. I am running MonoDevelop 3.1.

Comment: I also moved it to /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns, when I did that it complained that it couldn't find FSharp.Core.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close MonoDevelop, go to your package manager and install monodevelop-monogame.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no package named monodevelop-monogame in the synaptic package manager.  Could you please be more specific?